# Need trick to use cached value in nocache section

Tags: smarty, smarty3

I want to iterate thru single array and disable caching only for some elements.
So my idea was to keep `key` and get element by `key` in nocache section. Unfortunatelly i haven't found any possibility to:

assign cached `$rec@key` in nocache section,

or keep variable `key` definition in cached section.

Is there any way (without smarty code modification) to do it ?
here my test.tpl:

```
{foreach $array as $rec}
  {if $rec.dynamic}
    {assign var="key" value=$rec@key} 
    {nocache}
      {$array[$key].text}
    {/nocache}  
  {else}
    {$rec.text}
  {/if}
{/foreach}
```

and test.php:

```
<?php 
include_once 'libs/Smarty.class.php';
$smarty=new smarty();
$smarty->caching=1;
$smarty->assign('array',array(
            'r1'=>array('dynamic'=>true,'text'=>'dynamic'),
            'r2'=>array('dynamic'=>false,'text'=>'static')
          ));
$smarty->display('test.tpl');
```

(of course i will use it for much more complicated things than text display:) )
I tried lot of tricks and by myself i think it is not possible, please tell me i am wrong :)

Comment: I don't see {foreach} {nocace} {$rec@key} working in any way. What's keeping you from wrapping the whole {foreach} in a {nocache}?

Comment: I want to get as much as i can from smarty caching. It would be perfect solution for my CMS. In reality i will include different templates for each item. But i can have 2 instances of same module with different data, and i want to have single instance of "configuration" object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish is, as of Smarty 3.1.x, not possible. With 3.2 Smarty will allow you to "export" values into a {nocache} section to ensure they're available when the template is re-executed.

Until 3.2 is released (don't ask for a date, I don't know) you may be able to do this yourself using a compiler function.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I have found a solution: Use count in your loop.

```
    {nocache}
        {counter start=0 skip=1 assign="count"}
    {/nocache}
    {section name="co" loop=$publication}
        {nocache}
            {$publication[$count].id}
            {counter}
        {/nocache}
    {/section}
```